# Invalid type declaration for property 'completedSampleTreesCount' on 'Inventory': Cannot use shorthand '?' in 'type' when defining property objects

Tags: typescript, database, react-native, realm, schema

Here's my code for the Inventory object:

```
const Inventory = {
  name: 'Inventory',
  primaryKey: 'inventory_id',
  properties: {
    // other properties...
    completedSampleTreesCount: {
      type: 'int?',
      default: 0,
    },
    // other properties...
  },
};
```

I'm using Realm for my database in react native [ v0.72.3 ] app, and I believe the schema definition is correct based on the Realm documentation. I also made sure to have the correct version of Realm [ v12.0.0-rc.1 ] installed.

However, I'm still getting this error. I'm not sure what's causing it, and I need some help resolving it.

Could someone please explain why I'm getting this error when defining the completedSampleTreesCount property in the Realm schema? Is there something wrong with my schema definition or is there a specific way to declare optional properties in Realm?

Thank you!

Comment: What happens in the `?` is removed and you define the property as optional `optional: true,`?

Comment: It removes the error but what's wrong if i use `?` ... there are around 15 migration files and a lot of types defined in this app. I have to change them. I want to avoid this. @Jay

Comment: Maybe it would be a conflict to have a property that is optional (meaning it may not exist) but have a default value - it should be one or the other (just a guess). I would think the default would have to be null instead of a value.